# log4net log file not visible in Windows explorer in application installation sub folder

Tags: windows-installer, log4net, visual-studio-extensions, windows-explorer, vdproj

I use log4net for my desktop application written in c# and deployed using Visual Studio Extension "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" (MSI-Installer). After installation I do not see the log subfolder defined for log4net.

The TARGETDIR in "**Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects**" is defined as **`[ProgramFiles64Folder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`**.

The log4net log file is defined as

```xml
<appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
   <param name="File" value=".\log\MyApp.log" />
   <!-- ... -->
```

After installing the application via the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects"-created setup.exe and msi-installer I do not see
the log-folder in the Windows explorer under Program Files\MyManufacturer\MyProductName
although Show hidden files, folders, ... is set.

For testing purposes I added the following code to my application:

```cs
// does log file exist and grow ?
string currdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
MessageBox.Show(currdir, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
string[] sa = File.ReadAllLines(currdir + "\\log\\MyApp.log");
MessageBox.Show(sa.Length.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
// show lines created this year (2019)
string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < sa.Length; i++)
{
    if(sa[i].Contains("2019")) 
        s = s + sa[i] + "\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(s, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
```

So, the log file under **`Program Files\MyManufacturer\MyProductName\log\MyApp.log`**
can be accessed via the application and I see that it grows!

So the question is: Where is the log subdirectory ? How can I make it visible in the Wndows explorer ?
Is this a permission issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Short Version***: Please see if you have any **virtualized folders** under: 
>   **`%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore`**.
>
> If you see a redirected file written here, then you are seeing the result of redirected file writes due to lack of permissions to write to the
>   original location. It is a **policy controlled feature** with a number of snags to be aware of. Details below.

---

***Bitness?***: Are you sure you are looking in the right folder? Did you check in **`Program Files (x86)`** to be sure?

---

***Virtualization / Data Redirection***: I am wondering if you have policies enabled that auto-magically redirect failed writes in secured folders to another writable location? [**User Account Control: Virtualize file and registry write failures to per-user locations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-virtualize-file-and-registry-write-failures-to-per-user-locations).

***Data Redirect / Virtualization Policy Entry***:

> **Note**: The local security policy applet is available only in professional, enterprise and corporate editions of Windows. It will be lacking in "home editions".

To find and change this policy, please do as follows (or equivalent by other means):

1. **`Windows Key`** + tap **`R`**.
2. Copy & Paste: **`%windir%\system32\secpol.msc /s`**.
3. Click **`OK`** or hit **`Enter`**.
4. Navigate to: **`Local Policies\Security Options`**. Look for entry: **`User Account Control: Virtualize file and registry write failures to per-user locations`**.
5. Is this setting set to "**`Activated`**"?

> ***Prerequisite Conditions***: Even if this setting is set to activated, redirection only works under very specific circumstances.
>   For a program to be eligible for virtualization it must comply as follow:
>
> 1. ***Bitness***: Program must be 32bit.
> 2. ***Access Rights***: Must not run with administrator rights.
> 3. ***Manifest***: Must not have been compiled with a manifest file 
>      (indicating it is for Vista or later). Or you comment out the security
>      section.
>
> (see below for technical details on how to create a test application).
>   [**All of this from this source**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/please-explain-virtualstore-for-non-experts/d8912f80-b275-48d7-9ff3-9e9878954227). And [here is another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853363/129130).

***Task Manager & Virtualization***: You can see the **`virtualization status`** of a program by adding the **`Virtualization column`** to the Processes page in Task Manager (in Windows 10 use the Details view - it should say something like UAC-Virtualization there):

[image: Task Manager UAC-Virtualization]

***Where Does It Write?***: If this data redirection / virtualization setting is active, the log is redirected to a writable location automatically whilst still showing the original path in your application. Please check under:   **`%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore`**. Procedure:

1. **`Windows Key`** + tap **`R`**.
2. Copy & Paste: **`%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore`**.
3. Click **`OK`** or hit **`Enter`**.
4. Check sub folders (if any).

---

> ***Solution***: This problem can be dealt with in several ways.
>
> 1. ***Write Location***: Write to a writable location outright - by design. This is the only sane approach for the future in my opinion.
> 2. ***ACL Permissions***: You can open write permission to the location in question and allow users or everyone write access. I do
>      not like this approach security-wise.
> 3. ***Elevate***: I suppose you can run the application with admin rights by using an elevation manifest. I really do not like this
>      approach. Elevated applications are given "the keys to the city" and
>      represent a major security risk.
>
> There are some flavors of these "solutions", but I think I will
>   suggest these three for now. Maybe check the below link(s).

---

***Technical Notes***: Just for the record. With regards to the test application I used to debug:

1. Standard Windows Forms C# application.
2. On a button click event or directly in the main function: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Program Files\My folder\TestFile.txt", "Test");` (create path first and adjust "Program Files" part to your language)
3. `Project` => `Add New Item...` => `Application Manifest File`.
4. Comment out the whole `"Security"` section.
5. Compile a 32-bit executable.

Now try to build and run. You should see the application activated for virtualization in the **UAC-Virtualization column** of **Task Manager** (screenshot above). Clicking the button should write to `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore` if the data redirect / virtualization policy is active.

---

***Some Links***:

- [System.UnauthorizedAccessException while running .exe under program files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files)
- [Please explain VirtualStore for non-experts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/please-explain-virtualstore-for-non-experts/d8912f80-b275-48d7-9ff3-9e9878954227)
- [Inside Windows Vista User Account Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/cc138019(v=msdn.10)) - Mark Russinovich
- [Force an existing application to always run with UAC virtualization on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852967/force-an-existing-application-to-always-run-with-uac-virtualization-on)
- Patching Problems: [UAC Virtualization – Allowing standard users to update a system protected area](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrsnrub/2010/08/11/uac-virtualization-allowing-standard-users-to-update-a-system-protected-area/)

Comment: Yes, virtualization is activated and I found the log file in a sub folder of the VirtualStore.
Regarding your solution variant "Write location": I somehow hesitate to hardcode a writable
location in my application. For the time being I think I leave the application utilizing the VirtualStore.

Comment: OK, I guess the question is if it is OK for each user to have their own copy of the file - which I think they have when it is virtualized? Also see the link on "patching problems" above. Not a perfect match, but you should have a quick peek.

Comment: The drawback of using VirtualStore is that standard users do not see their AppData in the Windows explorer, as I just checked.
So they would have to be aware to either have an admin looking at the log file or to navigate to it in the cmd shell.
The only writeable location for a standard user I can think of would be %PUBLIC%\documents. provided this environment variable is set everywhere. 
What do you think ?

Comment: Would it work to write to the event log? I am not too up to speed on this. I suppose the ACL approach is the "least worst" - just open write access to a shared location? Could have problems if multiple users are logged on? All depends on the application. What would a shortcut in the start menu do? Would it open the VirtualStore file? I honestly really don't like any auto-magic redirection. So much confusion can result. Not sure what to "recommend".